# Is it OK to disabled the Indexing Service (cisvc.exe) on Server 2003 Running as a Web Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, indexing-service

Is it OK to disabled the Indexing Service (cisvc.exe) on Server 2003 Running as a Web Server? I only ask because it's hogging the CPU like crazy for hours and hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok, unless you need it (chance is low for that).

Or you just let it run - it uses very little cpu once it is finished with the initial indexing.